# How to navigate to a certain acticity in a chain without leaking memory

Tags: java, android

I have a user case like this:

Activity A -> B -> C ->D.

In the Activity D, I want to get back to the Activity A. I tried with Intent and it is okay, however, instead of reusing the existing one, it created a new one. Anyone please let me know how to cope it?

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is a fine topic on developer.android regarding exactly this question, check it out:
[avoiding memory leaks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the flags on the intent when you start A again

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class); 
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); startActivity(i);
```

see [public Intent setFlags (int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29)

for reference